# выводит фолс, а не тру

Tags: c

[image: при n=2212 все работает коректно]

помогите пожалуйста!

---

при n=2212 все работает коректно
помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `a==b==c` делает совсем не то, что вы думаете. Это сравнение `a` с `b`, после чего *результат сравнения* сравнивается с `c`...

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение вида `a == b == c` сделует записывать как

```
a==b && b == с
```